# How do I add hover cursor and still get move cursor on JQuery Table Sortable?

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

I have a table using jquery ui sortable applied to the tbody. When I drag the tr I have given it a move cursor. That works perfectly.

However the client wants a cursor on hover over the row so that they know it can be moved. I apply cursor: pointer to the tr using css. This then gives a point on hover over the tr rows.

The problem is if I then drag and drop the sortable I no longer get the move cursor.

Any idea how to get both a cursor on move and a different one on hover any sortable row?

Thanks

Graeme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement the 'start' event of the sortable to change your pointer (the hover tr pointer) with the drag pointer. On 'stop' you can change it back according to the mouse position.